# Rich Text Field File size limit

Tags: lotusscript, richtext

Is there a way to limit a file attachment to rich text field.
For example, i have a rich text called "temp", and i wanted to restrict
user to only attach 1mb file to it. Is this possible to lotusscript?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You cannot check the filesize before the attachment import, if you use standard RichtextItems.

You could make your own import button, which checks the filesize before attaching the file to a Richtextlite field.

Or you can just check the size after the user has saved the attachment.

Comment: So, how do I make a import button? Do I need to use lotusscript or formula? Thanks!

Comment: I would use lotusscript. Notesuiworkspace.OpenfileDialog for selecting the file.

Comment: One more thing, I'ved viewed the syntax here (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_OPENFILEDIALOG_METHOD_5310_ABOUT.html) and the example also is on how to delete a file. I'm sorry but how can I check the file size? Can you give me one example on how to make one? I really appreciate your help. :D